# shell_exec does not execute from browser requests

Tags: php, shell-exec

After the user submits a data via POST, I show a temporary page and do the process on the background with shell_exec, atleast that's what I'm trying to do.

Here's my page setup:

C:\laragon\www\index.php

```
<?php
    try {
        shell_exec("php " . __DIR__ . "/test.php");
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo "Exception: " . $e;
    }
?>
```

C:\laragon\www\test.php

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen(__DIR__ . "/testfile.txt", "w");
    echo "test";
?>
```

If I go to localhost or localhost/index.php, the second script doesn't run. However, when I try to call both scripts from cmd, it works with both of them.

```
php C:\laragon\www\index.php

php C:\laragon\www\test.php
```

They both work and create a file called testfile.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your webserver runs as a specific user and needs the path to `php.exe` as there is no path environment variable for the webserver user:

```
shell_exec("c:\path\to\php " . __DIR__ . "/test.php");
```

Comment: Running the script with
    shell_exec("C:\laragon\bin\php\php-7.2.11-Win32-VC15-x64\php.exe " . __DIR__ . "/test.php");
seemed to work. Doesn't shell_exec runs with base terminal?

Comment: See edit, it runs under the user that runs the webserver.  Same in Linux and I assume MacOS.

Comment: In cmd your user has a path var which seems to contain that path.  Do `echo %PATH%` and you will see.

Comment: This solved my problem with trying to run an R script. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! My god I've been here for hours. I have HTML that invokes a php script. You're exactly right the webserver didn't know the env variables, I was using Python however. my command looked like this: `/usr/local/bin/python3.7 /var/www/html/app/python_scripts/send_to_model.py'`