# Why does this PHP script with a shell_exec call run from the command line in Windows 10, but not the browser/localhost?

Tags: php, r, xampp, localhost, shell-exec

I'm using XAMPP on Windows 10, and trying to run a simple PHP script that uses the `shell_exec` function to call a simple R script in the same directory. Here's the PHP `index.php` file:

```
<?php

    echo shell_exec('Rscript test.R');
```

And here's the `test.R` file:

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

From the command line (i.e., Git for Windows), when I run `php index.php` in the folder, I get the following output:

```
[1] "Hello, World!"
```

However, when I run `index.php` from the web browser via XAMPP and `localhost`, I don't see anything on the page. At first, I thought it might be a permissions issue, so I gave **Full control** access to all users on the folder, but it didn't seem to change anything.

Any ideas on how to get this working from the browser? Thank you.

Comment: I would personnally have a look at the PHP log files to see if you get an error. You could also display them (see https://stackify.com/display-php-errors/). Probably `shell_exec` is disabled in the PHP INI for Apache. It could also have to do with the "safe mode". I'm sure you could find the answer on a forum. Good luck!

Comment: Patrick, thanks a lot for the comment and pointing me in a direction. Unfortunately, I'm not sure any of those things are the issue. I looked in the `php.ini` file, and nothing is listed for the `disable_functions` directive, and `shell_exec` isn't mentioned anywhere. Also, I added the three error-reporting lines recommended in your linked article to my PHP script, but nothing shows up. Lastly, it looks like "safe mode" in PHP was disabled in 5.4, and I'm using PHP 7.4 (http://php.adamharvey.name/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php). Any other ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer to the problem I was having. Apparently, even though `Rscript` is part of my Windows 10 `PATH` variable, when I try to execute an R script via `shell_exec` in PHP, I have to have the whole path to the Rscript executable (I guess because the PHP script / Apache server doesn't know about the path variable).

I changed the `shell_exec` function call as follows, and it worked:

```
echo shell_exec('"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.1.0\bin\Rscript" test.R');
```

Here's a link to the SO post that helped me figure this out:

[shell_exec does not execute from browser requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53617247/shell-exec-does-not-execute-from-browser-requests)